# How to get 20 days before one date format:YYYYMMDD

Tags: date, hive, hiveql

How to get 20 days before one date format:`YYYYMMDD`? Function `date_sub()` seems not working.

for example get date 20 days before `'20180912'` in Hive.

I am using `date_sub()` in joining two tables by date.

```
select a.*,b.*
from table1
left join
table2 
on
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1,'yyyymmdd'))=date_sub(date2,20)
```

and return nothing.

Comment: Can you share they query that you are trying out.

Comment: Correct format is 'yyyyMMdd'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are using is wrong one. Upper/lower case [matters a lot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Correct format is 'yyyyMMdd'.

Date_sub requires yyyy-MM-dd to work correctly, convert if necessary.

```
select date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180912','yyyyMMdd')),20) ;
OK
2018-08-23
```

`Cast as timestamp` **produces wrong result** **(1970 year), maybe it is an issue in my Hive version (1.2.1)**:

```
select cast(unix_timestamp('20180912','yyyyMMdd') as timestamp);
OK
1970-01-18 18:51:50.4
```

**Use** `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180912','yyyyMMdd'))` **for conversion, it works fine.**

Answer (score 1):

OK, date_sub can implement your requirement, like below:

```
select date_sub(CAST(unix_timestamp('20180912','yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP), 20) as date;
+-------------+--+
|    date     |
+-------------+--+
| 2018-08-23  |
+-------------+--+
```

And your join SQL could write like below:

```
select
    a.*,
    b.*
from
    table1
left join
    table2 on date1 = regexp_replace(cast(to_date(date_sub(CAST(unix_timestamp(cast(date2 as string),'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP), 20)) as string),'-','')
```

Comment: why I got all the values like '1969-12-30' or '1969-12-29'?

Comment: your orginal data in hive maybe 1970MMdd?